# Ajax-submitted form, no callback triggered

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form in a bootstrap modal, that I submit with Ajax. Up to this part, everything's good, the form is submitted and the datas are saved in the database. But, after this, no callback functions are triggered, neither complete, success nor error. I really struggle to see where this comes from.

Controller:

```
def create
@param = EventParam.new(event_param_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @param.save
    format.json { render json: @param }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @mail_template.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

JS:

```
$(".event-param-form").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
          $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",           
                  url: $(this).attr('action'),
                  data: valuesToSubmit,
                  dataType: "JSON",
          });
    }); 

    $('.event-param-form').bind('ajax:complete', function() {
           console.log("test");
           $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    });
```

Note that I also tried to use the callback success/complete from $.ajax() with no results.

Comment: It should be `format.js` not `format.json`, you're sending via javascript.

Comment: Indeed. i made the change, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use success method in ajax itself

```
 $(".event-param-form").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
          $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",           
                  url: $(this).attr('action'),
                  data: valuesToSubmit,
                  dataType: "JSON",
                  success : function(data){
                     //Success Call back
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('success');
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                  },
                  error  :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // Error Callback
                  }
          });
    });
```

Comment: as I have said, I tried that, I started by that, and it didn't work. It's really weird haha.